# "Object is not commit" when click show log or refresh

Tags: git, smartgit

When I click show log on SmartGit/Hg v6.0.7. I alway show warning "Command Failed":
- And I can't show Log.
- I try with ["HOWTO remove all dangling commits from your git repository"](http://www.tekkie.ro/news/howto-remove-all-dangling-commits-from-your-git-repository/). But I can't resolved it.

### Log.txt

```
16418321 (2014-10-10 13:57:57,193) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation > - Activation change from null to Shell {Command Failed}@1AE7852
16418322 (2014-10-10 13:57:57,194) [QThreadPoolThread-7 (smartgit.arf)] INFO       sc.file.monitor  - Collecting changes, pending trigger file count is 0 (latestSeq=304757)
16418324 (2014-10-10 13:57:57,196) [QThreadPoolThread-7 (smartgit.arf)] INFO       sc.file.monitor  - Collecting changes finished (latestSeq=304758)
16418415 (2014-10-10 13:57:57,287) [main] INFO              q.action  - Performing 'OK' button in window @1AE7852 owner @1DD8D46
16418415 (2014-10-10 13:57:57,287) [main] INFO              q.dialog  - Showed dialog 37 (@1AE7852) '@15D785C - Command Failed' (owner: @1DD8D46)
16418419 (2014-10-10 13:57:57,291) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  - Activation change from Shell {*Disposed*}@1AE7852 to Shell {huan-am - [C:\workspace\huan-am] - SmartGit/Hg 6.0.7 (for non-commercial use only)}@1DD8D46
16418420 (2014-10-10 13:57:57,292) [main] INFO  smartgit.repository.backgroundScan  - Starting background refreshing.
16419325 (2014-10-10 13:57:58,197) [QThreadPoolThread-7 (smartgit.arf)] INFO       sc.file.monitor  - Collecting changes, pending trigger file count is 0 (latestSeq=304762)
16419326 (2014-10-10 13:57:58,198) [QThreadPoolThread-7 (smartgit.arf)] INFO       sc.file.monitor  - Collecting changes finished (latestSeq=304763)
16419420 (2014-10-10 13:57:58,292) [QThreadPoolThread-7 (smartgit.aYt)] INFO       sc.file.monitor  - Collecting changes, pending trigger file count is 0 (latestSeq=304768)
16419422 (2014-10-10 13:57:58,294) [QThreadPoolThread-7 (smartgit.aYt)] INFO       sc.file.monitor  - Collecting changes finished (latestSeq=304770)
16419422 (2014-10-10 13:57:58,294) [QThreadPoolThread-7 (smartgit.aYt)] INFO  smartgit.repository.backgroundScan  - Running background refresh: []
16424255 (2014-10-10 13:58:03,127) [main] INFO              q.action  - Performing 'log, Log, Show the history for selected file or directory.'
16424285 (2014-10-10 13:58:03,157) [WorkerThread-1] INFO      smartgit.command  - Log [C:\workspace\huan-am] /
16424523 (2014-10-10 13:58:03,395) [WorkerThread-1] WARN       smartgit.review  - Remote 'origin' has ID, but is missing refspecs.
16424524 (2014-10-10 13:58:03,396) [WorkerThread-1] WARN       smartgit.review  - Remote 'huan-am' has ID, but is missing refspecs.
16424581 (2014-10-10 13:58:03,453) [WorkerThread-1] WARN       smartgit.review  - Remote 'origin' has ID, but is missing refspecs.
16424582 (2014-10-10 13:58:03,454) [WorkerThread-1] WARN       smartgit.review  - Remote 'huan-am' has ID, but is missing refspecs.
smartgit.eL: Object 226170739742f6e9ecb388888e88dcc3432bb667 is not a commit.
    at smartgit.oO.b(SourceFile:113)
    at smartgit.oN.a(SourceFile:266)
    at smartgit.oN.a(SourceFile:195)
    at smartgit.oN.a(SourceFile:170)
    at smartgit.aSQ.a(SourceFile:415)
    at smartgit.aSQ.a(SourceFile:119)
    at smartgit.aEC.a(SourceFile:113)
    at smartgit.aEC.a(SourceFile:179)
    at smartgit.bZ.a(SourceFile:42)
    at smartgit.lk.run(SourceFile:103)
    at smartgit.Tw.run(SourceFile:53)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.IncorrectObjectTypeException: Object 226170739742f6e9ecb388888e88dcc3432bb667 is not a commit.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseCommit(RevWalk.java:722)
    at smartgit.oO.b(SourceFile:110)
    ... 10 more
16424974 (2014-10-10 13:58:03,846) [main] INFO              q.dialog  - Show (warn): Command Failed - Executing a command has failed.
16424996 (2014-10-10 13:58:03,868) [main] INFO              q.dialog  - Showing dialog 38 (@EECB5C) '@16917F5 - Command Failed' (owner: @1DD8D46)
16425019 (2014-10-10 13:58:03,891) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  - Activation change from Shell {huan-am - [C:\workspace\huan-am] - SmartGit/Hg 6.0.7 (for non-commercial use only)}@1DD8D46 to Shell {Command Failed}@EECB5C
16425074 (2014-10-10 13:58:03,946) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  - Activation remains at Shell {Command Failed}@EECB5C
16426619 (2014-10-10 13:58:05,491) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  - Activation change from Shell {Command Failed}@EECB5C to null
```

> **`log.txt`** contains debug log information. It can be configured via log4j.properties.

That means `log.txt` will include the exact error which would explain why "Show Log" fails.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to describe your situations a bit more. Then, more people will be able to help you!

Comment: Sounds like SmartGit tries to access an SHA which it thinks is a commit but actually isn't. There should be a stracktrace in log.txt (see VonC's answer) ... send this one to smartgit@syntevo.com.

Comment: see what this shows - `git cat-file -p  226170739742f6e9ecb388888e88dcc3432bb667`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewC . I runned your command. And it show a file in my project. And I used TortoiseGit to show log of file. And I can see two commit of it. I runned `git checkout <SHA-1 oldest commit>`. But When I open Smartgit and click "Log" or "Refresh", the warning still popup with same info.

Comment: If it is a blob and not a commit then it sounds like a bug in smartgit.  Check the version you are running, upgrade if appropriate, and file a bug as @mstrap suggests

Comment: @AndrewC . Thanks. I think so. I will send log file to support.

Comment: Did you see an internal error, too?

Comment: @mstrap. No, I think It can't show log of repos because when I click "Log" the warning always popup about "object is not commit" , so I don't show log from git. Please see Error image: https://flic.kr/p/pEVyMB

Comment: Is is a public repository, so it can be reproduced by us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can report to the SmartGit "[Installation and Files](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/documentation/6/show?page=installation)" page:

### Default Location of SmartGit/Hg's Settings Directory

```
Windows 
%APPDATA%\syntevo\SmartGit\<major-smartgit-hg-version> (%APPDATA% is the path defined in the environment variable APPDATA)

Mac OS 
~/Library/Preferences/SmartGit/<major-smartgit-hg-version>

Linux/Unix 
~/.smartgit/<major-smartgit-hg-version>
```

### Notable Files in the Settings Directory

> **`log.txt`** contains debug log information. It can be configured via log4j.properties.

That means `log.txt` will include the exact error which would explain why "Show Log" fails.